# MVC - view variable?

Tags: model-view-controller

Using an MVC pattern say I have a view and a controller:

```
Controller
  User

View
  User
    login
    logout
    dashboard
```

The user controller has the following actions:

```
loginAction
logoutAction
dashboardAction
```

The login view has a simple login form, now my question:

Where should the form get its action url from?

Should this be hardcoded in the view such as:

```
<form action="/post.php" method="post">
```

It doesnt seem correct that the controller should tell the view, so where else could this go?

Comment: Why are you confusing views with templates ?

Comment: Im not following you sorry

Comment: Yes. That's part of the problem. Views in proper MVC are where UI logic is. They acquire information from model **layer** and, based on that information, decide how to present it (sometimes by combining multiple templates in HTML output). What you have there are just [templates](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html), which you call "views".

Answer (score 0):

The controller tells the view everything it needs, and the view displays it. The view has no knowledge of the controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-signin", ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>            
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "input", type = "text", placeholder = "Username" })     
    <br />
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "input", type = "password", placeholder = "Password" });
    <br /><br />
    <button type="submit">Sign in</button>            
}
```

In that login form, the link to the method on the controller is ("Login", "Account") where 'Login' is the method name and 'Account' is the controller name.